# USBDevice is not picking up linux computer

Tags: android, linux, usb

I'm trying to get an android app to communicate with a linux computer running ubuntu 12.04 lts using a usb cable. I'm trying to use the usbdeviceconnection class, but the usbdevice is not picking up the computer when i run it through debug mode or run the app normally. Was wondering if i had to configure the linux machine so that the app can pick up as an usb device or if there's another approach to this.

Comment: With the exception of some embedded machines, most Linux systems are only prepared to be USB hosts, and not devices, so this seems unlikely to work.

Comment: Is there any way around this such as using the Linux system as an USB accessory or would that be a wrong approach too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to get this to work through port forwarding. Here's the link if anyone else if looking for a solution to a similar problem to this: http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/comment-page-1/#comment-4139